# Values end up in same bucket with user-provided specialization of hash using std::unordered_set

Tags: c++, hash, bucket, unordered-set

I have this code where I define a custom hash for my type `X` to be able to store it in `std::unordered_set`. For that I use the address of the argument as shown below.

My first question:

> Why are all the `X`'es in the same bucket?

From [26.2.7 Unordered associative containers](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf) I know that:
"`Keys with the same hash code appear in the same bucket.`"
I also know that a better way to do this would be to define `operator()` as:

`auto operator()(X const &x) const { return hash<int>{}(x.m_i); }`,

but I want to understand what is happening here. It has to have something to do with `X{i}` being a temporary (a prvalue) - is the address of all `X{i}`'s the same? Is this defined or am I in UB-land?

My second question:

> What is changing / going on when I add `noexcept` to `operator()`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <unordered_set>

class X
{
  int m_i;

public:
  explicit X(int i) : m_i{i} {}
  auto operator==(X const &x) const { return m_i == x.m_i; }
};

template <>
struct std::hash<X> {
  auto operator()(X const &x) const { return hash<X const *>{}(&x); }
  // what's the difference to above version?
  // auto operator()(X const &x) const noexcept { return hash<X const *>()(&x); }
  // better:
  // auto operator()(X const &x) const { return hash<int>{}(x.m_i); } // better
};

int main()
{
  std::unordered_set<X> usx;

  for (int i{}; i < 10; ++i)
    usx.insert(X{i});
  for (std::size_t index{}; index < usx.bucket_count(); ++index)
    std::cout << "bucket[" << index << "]: " << usx.bucket_size(index) << '\n';
}
```

Output without `noexcept` (g++ 9.3):

```
bucket[0]: 10
bucket[1]: 0
...
bucket[12]: 0
```

Output with `noexcept` (g++ 9.3):

```
bucket[0]: 2
bucket[1]: 0
...
bucket[12]: 0
```

The output also varies with different compilers - with `noexcept` - (clang 12.0.0) for example gives:

```
bucket[0]: 0
bucket[1]: 0
bucket[2]: 1
...
bucket[12]: 0
```

Comment: Don't objects that compare equal also need to produce the same hash? Edit : [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) requirement #4 : For two parameters `k1` and `k2` that are equal, `std::hash<Key>()(k1) == std::hash<Key>()(k2)`.

Comment: If the hash is based on the address, and the hash can't change if you make a copy, you'll need to make sure the object is not copy-able or assign-able.  Then, if such a constraint is a problem, you'll see the fallout of not having those operations.

Comment: @François Andrieux This means, that using the address as part of the hash is never a good idea anyway, right?

Comment: @SebastianWilke For the purposes of using it with an unsorted container, it will never work. And in general, it is very unlikely to ever be useful. A hash should be representative of the *value* of an object, and an object's address is basically never part of its value. If it is, the object is also unmoveable and uncopyable and won't be used with containers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using the address of your structure as the hash mechanism instead of the structure itself. For example, in the following line:

```cpp
auto operator()(X const &x) const { return hash<X const *>{}(&x); }
```

You're getting a *pointer to* your newly created `x` and returning the hash based on that. Now, the reason that you're getting them all put in the same bucket is because the compiler uses the same memory location when you initialize a variable in a `for` loop. This means that the result of `&x` will always have the same value within the loop.

There are two things you could potentially do to get a different result. My recommendation would be to replace the above line with:

```cpp
auto operator()(X const &x) const { return hash<int>{}(x.m_i); }
```

but, you could also *probably* get away with:

```cpp
X x1(4);
X x2(5);

usx.insert(x1);
usx.insert(x2);
```

As this would probably have `x1` and `x2` at different addresses. This has a much greater potential to break though, since the memory location might end up being the same if you give the compiler a high optimization level.